# up, down and sideways

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

a. The ghosts moved up, down and sideways.

b. The ghosts moved up, down or sideways.

c. The ghosts moved either up, or down or sideways.

I see three possibilities:

1. All of them first moved up, then down and then sideways.
2. Some of them moved up, some moved down and some moved sideways.
3. The speaker doesn't know which way they moved. They might have moved up, or down or sideways.

I think (a) could mean (1) or (2).

(b) and (c) could mean (2) or (3).

Is that correct?

Comment: Without context, I would assume it to mean that they appeared capable of moving in any of those directions.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kate, for all your wonderful and kind replies. I really appreciate them. Let's say I walk into a haunted house and all of a sudden a number of ghosts come out and start moving up, down, and/or sideways. (The question was inspired by the song: 'Home By the Sea', It's a coincidence that I listened to it at a time near Halloween!)

Comment: Having looked up the lyrics, it appears that the ghosts were drifting about in all directions.